# can I run two threads at the same time in python function

Tags: python, api, twitter

I have created a function that calls twitter api to get last 200 tweets without retweets. It returns less than the tweets that covers the wanted timeframe `(last 28 days)`. each call needs (1.2sec) without processing the data. Totally I have three calls (user info, call 1, call 2 optionally if the last result from call 1 doesn't cover the wanted timeframe).

what I need here is to reduce the time `5.2sec` without processing the data.

My question is how to open another thread (if its possible), to open a thread if the last value is not in the timeframe. I need to open it from a function to call another function or any other suitable process. I'm kinda new in python so I would like to know if there is any possible way to achieve this claim.

If there is a sample code would be great

Cheers

Comment: No you can't that's what GIL in python......

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you tinkered with [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) library?

Comment: True parallelism in Python can only be achieved by using https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html instead of threads, because of the GIL.

Comment: @Narendra I saw some examples but I didn't understand it, that's why I asked if its possible

Comment: @Susensio I didn't check any code yet because I have no idea what are the limitations

Comment: @MikeScotty Thanks for the link, I tried to understand how should I use it but not yet, because one of the processes is calling api and the second is processing the values